# boost asio ssl handshake not sent after remote closes connection once

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I'm having trouble performing an ssl handshake after previous successful handshakes. Once connected and the handshake is complete, my client can transmit and receive successfully for a long time. Occasionally I'll get disconnect from the server with the error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.". When that happens, I cancel and close the socket on the client side. I can then connect again, but when I start an async_handshake nothing is transmitted to the server (wireshark shows no activity). Then I eventually get disconnected from the server again (presumably due to inactivity) with basically the same error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.".  I know that the client is sending and receiving data before the first disconnect - so inactivity is not the cause for that. Once in this state, the client can connect every time it tries, but the async_handshake never transmits anything and so the cycle repeats.

Any ideas?

Here's most of the code:

The connect:

```
    boost::asio::async_connect(
        m_socket.lowest_layer(), 
        endpoint_iterator,
        boost::bind(&CClientSock::handle_connect, 
        shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

and the rest

```
    void CClientSock::handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if ( !error )
        {
            m_socket.async_handshake(
                boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                boost::bind(&CClientSock::handle_handshake, 
                shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error)
                );
        }
        else
        {
            CloseSocket();
            m_eState = eDisconnected;
        }
    }

    void CClientSock::handle_handshake(
        const boost::system::error_code& error
        )
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            BeginRead();

            SendQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            CloseSocket();
            m_eState = eDisconnected;
        }
    }

    void CClientSock::BeginRead()
    {
        // Start an async read and always keep one going
        size_t bytes_transferred = BUFFER_SIZE;

        m_socket.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(rcvbuf, bytes_transferred),
            boost::bind(&CClientSock::handle_read, 
            shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void CClientSock::SendQuery()
    {
        m_eState = eSending;

        m_bTMO = FALSE;

        size_t request_length = 0;


    #ifdef _USE_MODBUSTCP
            sndbuf [0] = 0x00;
            sndbuf [1] = m_bTxn;    m_bTxn++;
            sndbuf [2] = 0x00;
            sndbuf [3] = 0x00;
            sndbuf [4] = 0x00;
            sndbuf [5] = 0x06;
            sndbuf [6] = 0x01;
            sndbuf [7] = 0x03;
            sndbuf [8] = 0x1B;
            sndbuf [9] = 0x59;
            sndbuf [10] = 0x00;
            sndbuf [11] = 0x01;
            request_length = 12;
    #else
            sndbuf [0] = 0x01;
            sndbuf [1] = 0x03;
            sndbuf [2] = 0x1B;
            sndbuf [3] = 0x59;
            sndbuf [4] = 0x00;
            sndbuf [5] = 0x01;
            sndbuf [6] = 0x52;
            sndbuf [7] = 0xFD;
            request_length = 8;
    #endif

        boost::asio::async_write(m_socket,
            boost::asio::buffer(sndbuf, request_length),
            boost::bind(&CClientSock::handle_write, 
            shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void CClientSock::handle_write(
        const boost::system::error_code& error,
        size_t bytes_transferred
        )
    {
        if ( !error )
        {
            // Already have an async_read started, so do nothing here.
            m_eState = eReceiving;
        }
        else
        {
            CloseSocket();
            m_eState = eDisconnected;
        }
    }


    void CClientSock::handle_read(
        const boost::system::error_code& error,
        size_t bytes_transferred
        )
    {
        if ( !error )
        {
            // start another async read
            BeginRead();

            // An external call starts another write when we're idle
            m_eState = eIdle;
        }
        else
        {
            CloseSocket();
            m_eState = eDisconnected;
        }
    }

    void CClientSock::CloseSocket()
    {
        bool bexcept = false;
        try
        {
    #ifdef _SSL_TEST
            if ( m_socket.lowest_layer().is_open() )
            {
                m_socket.lowest_layer().cancel();
                m_socket.lowest_layer().close();
            }
    #else
            if ( m_socket.is_open() )
            {
                m_socket.cancel();
                m_socket.close();
            }
    #endif
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            bexcept = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of canceling and closing the client socket after being disconnected, try creating a new socket.

Comment: That's what I'm testing now. Are there known issues with this?

Comment: I think the real question here is why is the server disconnecting? Once it's done that once, it seems to keep doing that to you forever. I doubt there is anything you can do about it from the client end.

Comment: The first disconnect does seem to be out of my control. But subsequent disconnects are no doubt due to the fact that the ssl handshake is never started from the client side...

Comment: If the `io_service` is running and the client's `async_handshake()` does not result in the `ClientHello` being sent to the wire, then I would attach a debugger and check for [system errors](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/4f11be277a/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp#L241), as there are a few cases where retry logic will mask recoverable errors.